# StackExchange HASH conversion to and from C# objects

Tags: stackexchange.redis

Is there any way to have a generic version of the HASH in StackExchange implementation of redis.
i.e. To convert a C# poco object to a hash and back from a hash to a C# object without going through a serialization process.